# CSS3 HTML5 scrolling issue

Tags: android, iphone, html, css, scroll

i'm making an interactive website for my local youth organisation! When i launch the website on my samsung galaxy S1 everything looks normal and it shows me the mobile website. But when i try to launch it on my Ipod 3G i cant scroll down([normal view](http://mockupr.com/mu/wgbj1841), [scroll down view](http://mockupr.com/mu/qxqm7906)). The website is: www.ksamerkem.be 
i would like to avoid anything but css3 or html5. I'm also using mediaqueries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to create the page using an iframe?

Your iPod cannot scroll down because your iFrame height is set to 100% which means there is no page scrolling required (all the scrolling is inside the iframe).

Cheers,

Mike

Comment: On looking at your site further it would appear that you are using the iFrame so that you can mask the real url of your site which is http://groep6040.ksjnet.be/ . You can test if it is the iframe that is causing the problem by seeing if you can scroll down the http://groep6040.ksjnet.be/ page using your iPod (I suspect you will be able to).

Comment: I cant change the code on my original website (www.ksamerkem.be) so how can i solve this problem?

Comment: This type of thing usually happens when you use a url masking service provided by your domain registrar because they rely on an iframe to work. You could try using domain forwarding to groep6040.ksjnet.be instead. The best solution though would be to host the whole site at www.ksamerkem.be instead of  groep6040.ksjnet.be but I don't know if that is a possibility for you.